# gsutil copy with multithread doesn't finish copying all files

Tags: multithreading, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We have around 650 GB of data on google compute engine.

We need to move them to Cloud Storage to a Coldline bucket, so the best options we could find is to copy them with gsutil with parallel mode.

The files are from kilobytes to 10Mb max, and there are few million files.

The command we used is

`gsutil -m cp -r userFiles/ gs://removed-websites/`

On first run it copied around 200Gb and stopped with error

`| [972.2k/972.2k files][207.9 GiB/207.9 GiB] 100% Done  29.4 MiB/s ETA 00:00:00 
Operation completed over 972.2k objects/207.9 GiB.

CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.`

On second run it finished almost at the same place, and stopped again.

How can we copy these files successfully ?

Also the buckets that have the partial data are not being removed after deleting them. Console just says preparing to delete, and nothing happens, we waited more than 4 hours, any way to remove those buckets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your first question, I can propose the several options. All of them based on data split and uploading by small portions of data.

1. You can try distributed upload from several machines.
   https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#copying-tofrom-subdirectories-distributing-transfers-across-machines

In this case you are splitting data by safe chunks, like 50GB, and uploading it from several machines in parallel. But it requires machines, that is not required actually.

2. You still can try such splited upload on a single machine, but you need then some splitting mechanism, which will not upload all files at once, but by chunks. In this case, if some thing fails, you will need to reload only this chunk. In addition, you will have better accuracy and you'll be able to localize possible fail place if something happens.

Regarding, how you can delete them. Well, same technique as for upload. Divide data on chunks and delete them by chunks. Or, you can try to remove whole project, if it suitable for your situation.

**Update 1**

So, I checked gsutil interface and it is supports glob syntax. You can match with glob syntax, for example 200 folders, and launch this command 150 time (this will upload 200 x 500 = 30 000 folders).

[image]

You can use such approach and combine it with `-m` option, so this is partially that your script did, but might work faster. This will work for folders names and files as well.
If you provide examples of the folders names and files names it would be easier to propose appropriate glob pattern.

Comment: how can i copy with gsutil specifying folder instead of just 1 ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. Are you asking about multiple destination/source folders setup?

Comment: Well, we have a folder in which there are around 30.000 folders which contains images.

as far as i know gsutil does not provide a way to copy from multiple sources at once.

Comment: I'm not sure that gsutil supports glob syntax, that might solve it, you need to check it. But, anyway, you can write some script, or bash file that will contains set of simple gsutil calls with specific folders.

Comment: I tried with php, did gsutil calls for the folders, but the overall speed went down to 1Mbps, seems kind of useless haha

Comment: I tried something similar, seems the best thing i could find for me is

```gsutil -m cp -r /folder/a* gs://XXX/```

Comment: so using the wildcard and break data into some logical chunks works the best

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are affected by [gs-util issue 464](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/464). This happens when you are running multiple gs-util instances concurrently wit the `-m` option. Apparently these instances share a state directory which causes weird behavior.

One of the workarounds is to add parameters: `-o GSUtil:parallel_process_count=1 -o GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=24`.

E.g.:

```
gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_process_count=1 -o GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=24 -m cp -r gs://my-bucket .
```

Answer (score -1):

I've just run into the same issue, and turns out that it's caused by the `cp` command running into an uncopyable file (in my case, a broken symlink) and aborting.

Problem is, if you're running a massively parallel copy with `-m`, the broken file may not be immediately obvious.  To figure out which one it is, try a dry run `rsync -n` instead:

```
gsutil -m rsync -n -r userFiles/ gs://removed-websites/
```

This will clearly flag the broken file and abort, and you can fix or delete it and try again.  Alternatively, if you're not interested in symlinks, just use the `-e` option and they'll be ignored entirely.

Comment: Tried this didn't help. I have no broken file. Still fails

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya If your error is "1 file/object could not be transferred", there's *something* wrong with that file.  Have you checked symlinks, permissions, mounts, ...?